# Facebook API: user_feed is empty

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth

So I was very happy when Facebook approved my Chrome Extension app. Basically, it allows you to import your data from facebook into the local_storage in Chrome, then you can easily search your old posts. While it works like a charm for my account, when I switch to another account, login, approve the Facebook request for permissions, my user_feed data is empty. I am at a loss.

I am able to get user info, the image of the user, his/her name, etc. and I am able to retrieve an access token. But, when I make the call to the feed, it comes back empty:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=EAAcu...&expires_in&limit=50&offset=1&fields=message,likes,story,created_time,link

(I have also tried injecting the ID for "me"). Again, this works great when it's my FB account (also the developer account). So, I don't think it is my code, the only thing that changes is the user...

Perhaps it takes a certain amount of time for the Facebook API to work even after Facebook approves your permissions request??

Comment: Oh, I'd like point out the link I posted is just an example, so it will not work as I truncated the access_token :-)

Comment: did you read about login review in the docs?

Comment: Yes, that is how I was able to get through the app review approval process (which took a few iterations of edits). I see all of the required permissions on my app page, it just doesn't have them when an access token is registered with Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) Tool to see if the access token that you are getting back has `user_posts` permission listed under "Scopes". If it is not present, then you cannot use that access token to fetch the user's feed.

Note that `user_posts` permission requires [approval](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_posts) prior to usage. If you are not approved, it will only work for people who have admin/developer role in your app.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I have this in scopes: user_posts, email, public_profile so I guess it must be something else...

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I didn't see this anywhere in the documentation, but in addition to having your app's permissions approved by facebook, you must also include the scope as a query parameter: 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=${appId}&scope=user_posts&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://someresponse.com

If anyone sees this in the documentation, please let me know.

Comment: You can find it in these two docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/permissions/

Comment: I wasn't very clear in my request for the documentation. I was specifically referring to the query string that includes the &scope request parameter. While there are several ways to use it with the SDK, there is no reference anywhere regarding &scope as part of the oauth URL. Thanks!